# BST Contains method not working properly in JAVA

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a method to see if a value exists in a BST.

```
 public boolean contains(int val){
        return containsHelper(val, root);
    }
    public boolean containsHelper(int val, Node root){


        if(val < root.val && root.left != null) {
            containsHelper(val, root.left);
        }
        else if(val > root.val && root.right != null) {
            containsHelper(val, root.right);
        }
        else { //theyre equal
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

I dont understand why my method isn't working, its going into the else where they are equal, but still returning false.

Comment: Hint: what if `val < root.val && root.left == null` ?

Comment: what if I change it to  else if(val == root.val) { //theyre equal
            return true; still getting same error

Comment: @Rachelle What is the error? We can't read your mind.

Comment: When it finds the element, it returns false even though it is going into the else where it should return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider adding an explicit base case. and an explicit case when you want to return true.

```
public boolean contains(int val){
    return containsHelper(val, root);
}
public boolean containsHelper(int val, Node root){
    if(root == null) return false;

    if(root.val == val) return true;
    else if (root.val < val) {
        return containsHelper(val, root.right);
    }else {
        return containsHelper(val, root.left);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This logic is not correct: `else { //theyre equal` is not correct.
In your code, this `else` block will also get executed when `root.left` or `root.right` is `null`
Code should look like this:

```
if(val < root.val) {
    if(root.left != null)
        return containsHelper(val, root.left);
    // not going to find val
    else return false;
}
else if(val > root.val) {
    if(root.right != null)
        return containsHelper(val, root.right);
    // not going to find val
    else return false;
}
else { //theyre equal
return true;
}
```